# What does this road sign mean? (Germany; red circle and X on a blue background, with a right-pointing arrow.)

Tags: legal, germany, driving, road-trips

Okay, I don't know why I'm having such difficulty finding an answer online. I found an example of the sign on Google Images but the hosting site is down and there is no cache, and searches using "blue background red cross white arrow" aren't turning up relevant results. [Update, 2019: Now they do! This page being the top result.]

[image: unknown road sign]

I'm driving for the first time in Europe—in Munich, Germany—and I came across an intersection where there seemed to a "main" signal above, straight ahead, and a "side" signal to the right, near the bicycle lane. The above pictured sign was affixed to its pole.

If this sign were standalone, there'd be less of a question about what it means. But...

1. It was a right turn from a smaller road to a main road, so it seemed unlikely that right turns wouldn't be allowed.
2. It was affixed to a side signal, so I thought it might mean to indicate that this side signal is a separate turn signal one should adhere to in order to make right turns (presumably to protect bicyclists and pedestrians).
3. A police car behind me, which I was nervously watching while waiting at the light, turned on *its* right-turn signal.

Was it fine to make a right turn? (The police didn't stop me, but I heard that you just get ticketed in the mail for violations.)

Comment: That means it's forbidden to stop or park, from the point you see the signal. Since it's an intersection and it has an arrow it means it's forbidden to stop or park to the right or left, depending on the arrow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25479/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-cheong-what-does-this-road-sign-mean-germany).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Provided there were no other sign or rule forbidding it, turning was perfectly fine. The red X cross on blue background means it's forbidden to stop (*absolutes Halteverbot*).

It's somewhat similar to the more well-known “no parking” sign, but stricter (parking is defined as leaving your vehicle or letting it stand longer than three minutes whereas this signs also covers shorter stops). *Waiting* because there is a traffic light, the conditions force you to come to a stop (traffic jam, emergency…) or the police orders it is explicitly allowed but *stopping* for any other reason (like letting someone get off your car) is not.

Arrows inside the circle are unrelated to any turn but specify the area of validity of the sign (it starts where there is a road-pointing arrow and ends where there is a an arrow pointing away from the road). In your case, and assuming the sign was placed on the right of the road, it would mean it's forbidden to stop before the sign (and the intersection).

I suspect it might have been affixed to another sign as a cost saving measure or to minimize obstruction and is completely unrelated to crossing rules for this intersection.

[More details are available on Wikipedia (in German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haltverbot)

Comment: Ah, so I misinterpreted the very basic meaning of the sign to begin with—it's forbidding one to _stop_, not forbidding one to _go_ one way or another. Thank you!

Comment: I think that the arrow sign indicates the side where the stop is forbidden

Comment: Just to add: In the UK this is known as a clearway, although the signs for it seem much less common than they once were.

Comment: @GuidoPreite No, the sign always refers to the side of the street it is on. The left arrow indicates the start of the no stop zone and an right arrow indicated that this is the end of the no stop zone. There is also one with arrows in both direction, which tells you that you are in a no stop zone and that you can neither stop directly before or after the sign.

Comment: @AndrewCheong At the end of the zone there is a [gray one striked throug](https://www.hkl-baushop.de/out/pictures/master/product/1/unbenannt-18(3).jpg). To give you an [overview](http://www.rsa-95.de/14/Haltverbot/Bilder-Beitrag/Geltung-EB-Plan-02neu.bmp) about the arrow-directions.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Not quite. The two sings you linked to denote a "zone", i.e. an *area* in a city, inside which parking is prohibited *anywhere*. The sign the OP refers to denotes a section of a single road/street where stopping is prohibited on the right side of the road. The "end of zone" sign cannot terminate the unrelated Halteverbot sign of the OP.

Comment: I sourced this link from one of the comments, it translates well, and has a wealth of information on this interesting sign!    [Link](http://www.rsa-95.de/14/Haltverbot/Haltverbote.htm)

Comment: @DoverAudio Readers should just be aware that it mostly lists instances were the sign was used wrongly by the local authorities and the resulting confusion on what rule to follow.

Comment: In other words, what Americans would call a "no standing zone"?

Comment: The arrows make more sense if you imagine the signs _facing the street._ (And, indeed, they are often mounted in a somewhat angled diagonal orientation to make this easier to see.) Facing the street, one arrow would point in the driving direction and indicate "from here", the other one against the driving direction, indicating "up to here". Imagine the following ASCII art representing the right side of the street: ____________->... no stopping here ... <-__________

Comment: @PeterSchneider Great way to visualize it, thanks!

Comment: WRT your "_Waiting_ because there is a traffic light (..) is explicitly allowed", I have never, ever seen a stopping prohibited sign in front of a traffic light. That would have been so silly that I would have remembered.

Comment: @MrLister I don't see why it would be silly, quite the opposite.

Comment: What, a "no stopping" sign and a red traffic light? I find that hard to reconcile.

Comment: @MrLister It's quite simple, on a main thoroughfare, you don't want motorists to impair traffic by loading or unloading things but have traffic lights to regulate the flow precisely because traffic is too high for other types of crossings.

Answer (score 30):

Red circle means Prohibition, round signal means law-enforced (as per driving code and rules), upper left to lower right red bar means prohibition to park your vehicle (2 or more minutes and stopped engine supposes  your car is parked) and upper left to lower right with a 'mirrored' lower left to upper right red bar means prohibition to park or pulling over your car(be it to get up or down your car people or things) and the white  arrows indicate "from this sign up the  direction the arrow is pointing".

With exception of the arrow, this sign is internationally standardized by the [Vienna Convention on Road Signs and Signals](http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/trans/conventn/Conv_road_signs_2006v_EN.pdf) (though not all signatories use this sign) as laid down in part 1, annex 1, section C II, Nr. 9.

[image: Standing and Parking Prohibited (sign C, 19)]

Comment: Are those international standards for traffic signs?

Comment: It's the same in Russia. Except we don't have the white arrows.

Comment: @Mindwin Yes, those are all laid down in the Vienna Convention on Road Signs and Signals. Specifically the question is about sign C, 18.

Comment: Can you add that info to the answer, and provide a link to that convention? It would improve the answer greatly (the comments are volatile. P.S.: @neo i only noticed after posting that you aren't the answer poster.... lolz.

Comment: @neo Cheers to Creative Commons. `site design / logo © 2015 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev usually the arrows, if they exist at all, are placed in a white rectangular sign below the sign, I didn't know the germans put them on the sign itself. 

Also to avoid the confusion the arrows are often vertical, like this (ignore the graffiti on the double arrows in the reminding signs): 
http://www.sicurauto.it/upload/news_/14310/img/9382-divieto_fermata.jpg

Comment: @Formagella: yes, we have _those_ here :)

Answer (score 0):

> What does this road sign mean?

It means you should do at least the theory part of the german driving license before driving around there clueless.

Here are the official rules (StVO = Straßenverkehrs-Ordnung):

https://www.juris.de/purl/gesetze/_ges/StVO

You should know them before even starting the car engine on a parking lot.

I would never drive in another country without getting familiar with the rules there, even if it's a similar country like Austria or Switzerland, there are such big differences, that they might cost lives.

To the question: The sign means no stopping, the arrows indicate the direction in which stopping is not allowed.

Usually the signs are parallel to the road, so the direction is clear. If you have a no stopping sign facing you while you drive, below a traffic light or such, imagine it rotated to the street.

A sign without arrows facing you means from here on, rotated to the side, it is usually a reminder for people who missed the start of the no stopping area. There's also those with two arrows.

That's already pretty complicated and that was only one sign. We have a lot more of those. Imagine additional signs for hours, types of vehicles and parking tickets. When do you need to buy one, when is it allowed to park, and so on.

Then there's people who do dangerous stuff like a full braking because of a speed limit that only applies to trucks with dangerous chemicals, suprising all the normal drivers behind them. And yes, that's the normal mode in germany, without a reason a car does not brake just for fun or without indicating it before.

It's just foolish to assume you will figure it out while driving, learn it before you start.

Comment: So I take it, you have either never driven in Austria or Switzerland or if you have, you have memorised all of [these](http://www.astra.admin.ch/dienstleistungen/00127/00634/index.html?lang=de) and [these](http://www.wien.gv.at/verkehr/verkehrszeichen/vorschrift.html) as well as the whole road code for both countries? On another note, this should probably be a comment as it really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Usually someone with local knowledge is driving me around, but yes, If i were to drive myself, I would learn those. Just like I learned the german system to drive here. Are you suggesting you would not because it is too complicated? How would you figure it out when you came in a dangerous situation?

Comment: I always thought airports should sell or give away little booklets "German traffic rules for Americans", "German traffic rules for British" etc. (obviously the other way round in other countries), explaining not the complete rule set, but the differences.

Comment: the signs are set by the vienna convention so there's no need to learn them anew. 
You just need to know them in the first place to get your driving license. 
A refresh might be useful because some might be uncommon in your country. 

I think the most critical for americans is that you can't overtake on the right and that the motorway lanes are overtaking lanes, not fast or slow lanes.

Comment: @Formagella beside the internationally standardised signs each country has some of its own as well. These arrows on no-stop signs in Germany are one such example. I've never encountered them anywhere else. In the Netherlands there can be arrow signs mounted beneath the sign to specify it further, also an extension of the international standard.

Comment: I don't disagree with you that the better one is informed, the safer one keeps their selves as well as others. In general. But your argument is a [slippery slope](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/assets/FallaciesPosterHigherRes.jpg) argument, too. I did read up on German signs and laws, but it simply wasn't enough to reforge my 10 years of associating with US road signs only. Still, to say that I'm putting lives at risk is extreme. I use common sense and experience. I do as other drivers do for example—if every car is turning right and not going straight for some reason, I turn right too, even

Comment: if it takes me off-route—maybe I missed a sign or something. I don't ever make turns without looking for pedestrians, bicycles, etc. so even if I think I have the right of way, I won't harm anyone. One good argument is that by doing so I may create unexpected stops for drivers behind me—but I drive defensively—I _never_ just suddenly brake; if it's too late to make a turn or to pause to look for pedestrians / bicyclists, I'll just continue straight and loop around. On highways, I never linger in another car's blindspot, and if the car behind me's not keeping proper distance, I add extra

Comment: distance to the car in front of me, myself, in case everyone needs to sudden-brake (then I can buffer my braking to give the car behind me more time). Strategies like this, to me, make more of a difference to "costing lives," than not being able to memorize law. I once took an (extra, self-paid) defensive driving course, where they had me drive on a wet surface and intentionally lose control, to learn how to stay calm and steer myself back into traction. I could argue that _you_ are endangering lives by not seeking out and taking that course. But that's a ridiculous, hyperbolic argument.

Comment: @Formagella, the U.S. is not a signatory to the Vienna convention, so many Americans would have to learn them from zero.

Comment: It's not just signs that are different. I was quite surprised that in the USA a "Stop" sign apparently means "Stop, then the first one at the crossing proceeds carefully", and not "Stop, then give way" like in Germany.

Comment: Even something simple as a traffic light showing red may have different meanings, e.g. with respect to right turns being allowed or not - AFAIK in the case of the USA even differing from state to state,

Comment: @gnasher729 We have *both* types of stop sign that you describe. The first is an "all-way" or "4-way" stop, where both (to simplify) streets have stop signs. These signs function as a first-in-first-out queue, although sometimes you can cheat a bit if you are going exactly opposite the car which is entitled to enter the intersection. But we also have stop signs where the main road has no sign, and these are stop-and-yield until clear. (The latter was once called a 'boulevard stop', but I have not seen this phrase more recently than 80-year-old novels.)

Comment: @gnasher729 Stop signs will be labelled "4-way" (or all way or similar, as appropriate) or something like "cross street does not stop", so you know what you're supposed to do.