# Resource to lookup local driving habits

Tags: driving

Often times I rent a car when I travel. However in some countries locals do not follow the signs / speed limits / etc. While in other counties it would be costly to go even 10km/h above the limit. There are even countries which do not fine until you go 20+km/h above the limit by law.

Also in some countries it's common to bribe the police, while in others you probably will be out to jail for that.

Is there any resource where I can lookup all these little nuances before I hit the road?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a website or resource that lists specific traffic rules or specific signs for each country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50460/is-there-a-website-or-resource-that-lists-specific-traffic-rules-or-specific-sig)

Comment: Thx for the link. While it partially covers my question, I'm more interested in what is the road culture and how locals behave on the road type of information, rather than formal rules. Often time those two do not match one another

Comment: I’m not sure how knowing nuances like locals not following the signs/speed limit would be of much help, the rules are the rules and you should follow them regardless of other people’s driving practices

Comment: In some places locals will not be fined but our of town / state / country visitors will get fined. Last I heard this happening is somewhere in the USA, but I guess it will be common in more places.

Comment: You _could_ just follow the speed limits not to risk anything?

Comment: @Lundin In some places, because everyone speeds, just driving at the speed limit could be dangerous in itself.

Comment: @PeterM Kind of depends on what type of road it is and how well the speed limits are set in relation to how fast you can actually drive safely on that road.

Comment: It also depends on how 'local' the region is. If every driver except you is a friend or family of the police officer: you will be the one who is stopped.

Comment: Knowing how the locals drive also doesn’t help much if you are say driving a newly picked-up rental car and are unfamiliar with its controls, the route and maybe even with driving on the left instead of the right.  In the event of an accident because you were ‘doing what the locals do’ I’m not sure an insurance company would have much sympathy. Eg locals will speed because they know the road and will be aware of upcoming potential hazards (and likely police speed checks).

Comment: A simple Google search "driving habits in XXX" will generally yield useful results . I don't think there is a consolidated website for this. You only need the info for the country you are currently driving in